# When I run my tex file, some text is missing

Tags: itemize, enumitem

```
\begin{description}[font=$\bullet$~\normalfont\scshape\color{red!50!black}]

\item [In Zeile 1 habe ich mir ein Curses Bibliothek geholt.Curses ist der name verschiedener Programmbibliotheken zur darstellung von Text User interface(TUI).Ein User Interface ist eine Schnittstelle,über die eine Person eine Software oder Hardware kontrollieren kann. Die navigation erfolgt in der Regel über die Tastatur und nicht über die Maus.]
\end{description}
```

And then when I run this file some text is just missing

[image: Output]

Comment: @gernot - This posting is *not* a duplicate of the earlier posting you found. In the earlier posting, there was a legitimate need to use a `description` environment; the only task was to find a way to permit suitable line breaks. The present posting features none of that. Instead, it's an example of a gross mis-use of the `description` environment. The OP should have been using an `itemize` environment all along.

Comment: @Mico You are right ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're mis-using the `description` environment. You should be using an `itemize` environment instead. E.g.,

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor,babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[before=\scshape\color{red!50!black}]
\item In Zeile 1 habe ich mir ein Curses Bibliothek geholt. Curses ist der 
  name verschiedener Programmbibliotheken zur darstellung von Text User 
  interface (TUI). Ein User Interface ist eine Schnittstelle,über die eine 
  Person eine Software oder Hardware kontrollieren kann. Die navigation erfolgt
  in der Regel über die Tastatur und nicht über die Maus.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```